# Expecting delimiter in .bin file

Tags: python, file, io

I'm currently working with several .bin files generated by an oscilloscopes' software. These .bin files consist of header and 1.5k points on the screen.

A part of a program I wrote to work with those .bin files extracts header and converts it to JSON format.

The bytes from the files are stored as `good_bytes` and `bad_bytes` in the example below.

With this `good_bytes` my program works excellent, however, with `bad_bytes` the program returns this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user1/stack_overflow/read_osc_file_orig.py", line 520, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/user1/stack_overflow/read_osc_file_orig.py", line 515, in main
    json_data = HeaderToJSON(data_file)
  File "/home/user1/stack_overflow/read_osc_file_orig.py", line 507, in HeaderToJSON
    return json.loads(chID)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 820 (char 819)
```

I tried looking through both bins with `hexdump` command but found no difference. What could be a problem and how should I correct it?

The core function for extracting JSON:

```py
def HeaderToJSON(file):
    start = file.read(10)
    print(start)

    chID = bytes()
    count = 0
    while True:
        s = file.read(1)
        chID += s
        if s == b'}':
            count += 1
            if count == 6:
                break

    noise2 = file.read(4)

    return json.loads(chID)
```

The full testcase is:

```py
import json
from io import BytesIO

bad_bytes = (
    "5350425844534a0300007b2254494d45"
    "42415345223a7b225343414c45223a22"
    "352e307573222c22484f464653455422"
    "3a2d3430327d2c2253414d504c45223a"
    "7b2246554c4c53435245454e223a3135"
    "32302c22534c4f574d4f5645223a2d31"
    "2c22444154414c454e223a313532302c"
    "2253414d504c4552415445223a222831"
    "30304d532f7329222c2254595045223a"
    "2241564552616765222c224445504d45"
    "4d223a22314d222c2250524543495349"
    "4f4e223a327d2c224348414e4e454c22"
    "3a5b7b224e414d45223a22434831222c"
    "22444953504c4159223a224f4646222c"
    "2243757272656e745f52617465223a31"
    "303030302c2243757272656e745f5261"
    "74696f223a31322e352c224d65617375"
    "72655f43757272656e745f5377697463"
    "68223a224f4646222c22434f55504c49"
    "4e47223a224143222c2250524f424522"
    "3a22313058222c225343414c45223a22"
    "3230306d56222c224f4646534554223a"
    "35302c224652455155454e4345223a30"
    "2c22494e5645525345223a224f464622"
    "7d2c7b224e414d45223a22434832222c"
    "22444953504c4159223a224f4e222c22"
    "43757272656e745f52617465223a3130"
    "3030302c2243757272656e745f526174"
    "696f223a302e3632352c224d65617375"
    "72655f43757272656e745f5377697463"
    "68223a224f4646222c22434f55504c49"
    "4e47223a224143222c2250524f424522"
    "3a223158222c225343414c45223a2231"
    "30306d56222c224f4646534554223a33"
    "312c224652455155454e4345223a3330"
    "3033302e3033312c22494e5645525345"
    "223a224f4646227d5d2c224441544154"
    "595045223a2253435245454e222c2252"
    "554e535441545553223a225452494722"
    "2c2249444e223a224f574f4e2c584453"
    "33323032412c313732303039312c5632"
    "2e382e342e30222c224d4f44454c223a"
    "22333230323031313032222c22547269"
    "67223a7b224d6f6465223a2253494e47"
    "6c65222c2254797065223a2245444745"
    "222c224974656d73223a7b224368616e"
    "6e656c223a22434832222c224c657665"
    "6c223a222d32342e306d56222c224564"
    "6765223a2252495345222c22436f7570"
    "6c696e67223a224443222c22486f6c64"
    "4f6666223a223130306e73227d2c2253"
    "77656570223a224155544f227d2c2249"
    "73536b69704966436c6f736564223a74"
    "7275657de00b00005afcc2fd2cfd83fd"
    "e9fce0fd50fdadfd18fdd8fd85fdc6fd"
    "79fd06feadfd3efecefd70fe8dfd56fe"
    "acfdc2fe83fd9dfe73fdb4fec1fdc8fe"
    "fbfdc9fec5fd4cff4efe01ff0cfe57ff"
    "47feeefe29fe20ff79fed4fe63fe41ff"
    "7dfe04ff92fe2affc8fe30ffbcfe48ff"
    "d3fe32ffc0febefffefe4dffa5febeff"
    "0cff6cffccfea1ff06ff7cffd2fe8eff"
    "1dffa4ffd9febfff28ff95ff2bffc2ff"
    "54ff99ff49ffc5ff71ffc5ff62ffd5ff"
    "77ffbaff81ffc9ff6affc9ff6fffecff"
    "4ffff0ff6dfff7ff7cff19008bff1700"
    "92ff000099ff0d009efffdffaafff6ff"
    "acfffcffbdff0400b5ff0500a6ff0c00"
    "c7ffffffc4ff0a00dcfffdffccff0f00"
    "c8ff1500bdff3c00baff2100c9ff3000"
    "d4ff4500bdff3400c9ff4500cfff3800"
    "b0ff4300ceff4000c7ff4400dcff5000"
    "d8ff5000e8ff4e00edff3d00e4ff3900"
    "ecff3300f3ff4f00f8ff4a0000004300"
    "0700560004004e0003004000feff5c00"
    "07005f00000054000d00530000004e00"
    "edff4d00f1ff4b00f9ff470006007100"
    "0e0072000600730001006d001c006100"
    "c4ff7d000c005c00f6ff8f0041006d00"
    "1f009500530083003e0095005b00be00"
    "5800e2007600d20065001d01be001901"
    "7b006e01ce006c01f800e70145013c02"
    "8d015a02e9010903400238037b02d403"
    "24035804840368056804e4054205a606"
    "e805fd064306b907ac0634088207ff08"
    "97079709f608e609ae08fb092509f509"
    "ec08520a53096c0a95092a0b3f0a860b"
    "9a0a9f0b0b0bc70b090bd70b460b910b"
    "260bbc0b280bf80b850b220c960b1d0c"
    "ab0b1b0c8d0bee0b350bbb0cb10bcc0c"
    "960bfa0cc50b080dda0b8e0ce80b790c"
    "980b980cbf0b8c0cfa0bd10ced0b940c"
    "1d0c9d0c270c8b0c0d0c720c2e0c8f0c"
    "1d0c910c3a0ca70c450ca90c680c9e0c"
    "580c8e0c310ca00c270c810c2b0c910c"
    "1f0c980c200cb10c170cb50c4d0cc20c"
    "510ce00c640ceb0c7a0caa0c320cb00c"
    "2f0c940c3b0c9c0c130cc20c280cd10c"
    "350cc10c470ccb0c810cbe0c650cac0c"
    "410c8c0c380c8d0c240c880c370caf0c"
    "4e0cb50c450ca30c460c8c0c2c0c7e0c"
    "180ca60c370cc80c4f0c150d230c7b0c"
    "5e0b3a0dd90ba30cbb0bf80cf20bd90c"
    "2c0c150d870cc50c1c0ca80c390c800c"
    "e70bab0c110cfc0c700c180d820b830c"
    "830b020dd00bcb0c5c0bdb0c390c4c0d"
    "0d0c480e5a0c480d020c310dac0bd30c"
    "680b5d0cbe0b520ce10ab30c2b0bd20c"
    "fe0b400d030c6b0d3e0ced0c000c5b0d"
    "c40bb40cb70b400d990b160de80bcd0c"
    "fd0b140db70b9a0c7a0b550c6e0bbe0c"
    "550b6c0c7d0beb0c0c0c4b0db40cb80d"
    "e90c7a0d9f0cd20cf00b230c870b1d0c"
    "6a0b330cae0b9c0cc70bdd0c770ccb0c"
    "300ca70cd00b990cef0bc20c360c5b0d"
    "600c540d740cf10c660ce50cd90b3f0c"
    "bb0bef0b710b7c0c900b740c170cc30c"
    "4b0cce0c570cbe0c5c0cb50c270c760c"
    "2c0c8f0c310c9f0c360c990c480c890c"
    "440c8b0cfa0b620cf30b480cef0b690c"
    "fe0b9e0c0d0cc30c3c0ce20c8a0cd30c"
    "330cd20c4c0c8b0c230c540cd00bd40b"
    "aa07f8065eff8afe4af7bcf633f3f3f2"
    "dbf0ebf034f052f014f08af031f0b8f0"
    "50f012f1a3f0f9f0a9f038f1def053f1"
    "daf078f119f196f16af034f15ef004f2"
    "43f1f5f148f1b5f2fef1acf205f2c3f2"
    "29f2ccf2f6f1d0f21ff20ef383f27af3"
    "c7f2c4f332f308f45cf331f4b3f39bf4"
    "e0f328f52cf45af5b1f3caf64ff42cf7"
    "eff4fbf7c4f542f851f64af8bef65ef8"
    "e4f69cf85ef7a6f80df8bff980f8bdf9"
    "33f917fa8cf958fab0f974faf1f9a3fa"
    "2afad5fa62fa41fbaffa5bfbb7fa06fc"
    "1ffb84fc72fbeffb5bfb6dfc98fb41fc"
    "71fbbcfc92fbb2fc91fbf0fc2ffc19fd"
    "43fc47fd9dfc4afda9fc75fdc0fc5cfd"
    "d6fc7bfd1bfd89fd3efdb4fd65fdbefd"
    "7bfdd7fd8dfdebfd93fd13fe93fd2bfe"
    "b8fd63fea4fd92fed1fd8efefefda5fe"
    "15fe98fe1bfe95fe3ffea6fe2ffeb8fe"
    "5dfebafe5afedcfe79fee7fe87fe14ff"
    "9dfefafe81fe13ffa4fe0cffb5fe23ff"
    "cbfe21ffd3fe38ff05ff4ffff1fe62ff"
    "e0fe66fff9fe6cffd6fe82ffdcfe82ff"
    "02ff87ff15ff9cff1effaeff22ffa6ff"
    "42ffa1ff4effa8ff59ffa2ff5fffafff"
    "71ffb5ff74ffc2ff89ffc4ff8bffe6ff"
    "7effe4ff5fffd9ff77ffffff6ffff1ff"
    "84ffeeff8ffffcffa2fffcff9dff0800"
    "bdffffff7bff13008fff090056ff2600"
    "81ff1200a2ff4000adff3a00b9ff3100"
    "b3ff2000bfff0d00baff0e00ceff1400"
    "d4ff1a00f1ff1e00e8ff4d00f9ff3e00"
    "95ff5100baff230051ffb4006eff3200"
    "a3ffd000b6ff97009aff9f00ddff7200"
    "baff6c00dfff4f00b4ff4800e3ff3a00"
    "ebff5f00f6ff5800faff560003003e00"
    "efff6100e1ff4f00bcffcd009bff8000"
    "bfffb700d4ffc000d8ff9200deff8900"
    "b3ff7700e4ff8300bdff7700f9ff6c00"
    "00008100140073001d007c0025007100"
    "2f007d001800980015008e0038009400"
    "3b0090004c00ba005000be006300fa00"
    "8e001601c0007f01d400a0010b01d901"
    "2a01e40171013a028201890212022103"
    "7102aa0322035004ae0308056204a405"
    "1a0536069c05c60630066407d206e407"
    "68075808e207b9085c08f4088f085609"
    "df08b10943092a0a7909ae0a130af20a"
    "690a1c0bbe0a290ba90a510bd20a470b"
    "e50a830b2e0ba50b430bd80b700bc80b"
    "750be30b770be40b8b0bf00b940b410c"
    "d20b700ce30b8e0c280c640c060c580c"
    "f80b570c0d0c930c0c0c700c490bd10c"
    "550bd70ca30bdb0c900b1d0d4c0c180d"
    "380c170d030c9d0ce50b910cd10b920c"
    "ed0b9f0c210c920c320c960c4e0c9d0c"
    "320cce0c370ce60c4f0ce90c470b1b0d"
    "fe0ad20d860c310d980b9f0d940c500d"
    "190c380daa0b720c660bea0cc50bbd0c"
    "d80bd70c450cc60cf70bf40c240c830c"
    "de0bdd0c170cf10c030ce60c010c320d"
    "f80b200dd30b350d580b0b0d0f0c800c"
    "b90b180d980bb00cb40bd40c7a0b7e0d"
    "840b350d780cb10dd80c6f0d210caf0c"
    "170c860c580b450c930b870ce90b340d"
    "6c0c2e0d900ce60c740cbe0cee0b5b0c"
    "c80b4f0cc70b840cd30bfd0c330c3b0d"
    "7c0c4d0dbe0cf70c1b0c930cdf0b2d0c"
    "a60b5c0cb90ba70cd40b0d0d560c060d"
    "8b0c0f0d7c0cb00c330c960c330c920c"
    "300ccb0c3d0cb90c600cad0c630cb10c"
    "430cac0c250c680c060c8a0c0f0cbd0c"
    "4a0cca0c310cc90c4f0cb30c610ca00c"
    "3c0c960c310c8e0c410c830c460c900c"
    "400c780c2d0c990c2b0c8b0c440c8a0c"
    "3c0c8b0c440c900c4a0ca80c490cc30c"
    "5c0ce90c7d0ce70c2a0c5a0c530bda0c"
    "770ba00c8f0bfa0ccc0bf50c770c480d"
    "a50c010d1f0c970c100c6a0cea0b3c0c"
    "8e0ba00c8c0be90c390c050d290c340d"
    "790cc50c6d0ca40ca20b6c0c920bcb0c"
    "de0b6b0d060cc60d360c800c340b310d"
    "c10b3a0cfb0a7e0cd20be80cb50b7a0d"
    "2a0c7e0c4b0a0a0a2f0233016af9acf8"
    "d1f3f9f32ff170f145f0c8f03df0aff0"
    "22f094f0f4ef62f0eaef9cf0d0ef81f0"
    "f5ef27f257f064f204f15ff23af1eaf2"
    "20f187f1b8f08cf188f0e1f14cf0f1f1"
    "6af1c6f2baf12af34bf262f387f289f3"
    "78f231f3a4f26af3d6f2a6f30ef318f4"
    "93f377f4fbf3e9f409f43af56bf46af5"
    "e7f438f627f588f6d2f574f781f6daf7"
    "fff625f884f788f8e1f7cdf83bf817f9"
    "a1f891f908f9cbf961f918faaef955fa"
    "c4f9c9fa29fae1fa59fa5bfbccfa77fb"
    "d1fa95fbfcfaa4fb54fb00fc7afbfbfb"
    "75fb76fccafb8efcccfbadfc01fcbffc"
    "44fce9fc77fc1bfd6bfc1bfdbbfc2afd"
    "cbfc3efdf7fc76fd1dfd7ffd2ffd9dfd"
    "54fdb6fd6efddbfd8bfde4fd8efd09fe"
    "aafd2afebcfd54fe93fd69fe1afe6dfe"
    "9afdeffe33fe7afeaffd29fffefde3fe"
    "adfd0bff12fec7fe2cfe18ff44fe08ff"
    "47fe18ff83fe07ff85fe13ff9dfe08ff"
    "b8fe14ffc3fe2affe5fe2effe6fe49ff"
    "fffe45ffd5fe67ff0dff60ffcffeeaff"
    "f5fe88ffa0fe0000e3febcff7cfefeff"
    "2cffc1ffcafe03002bffbbfff7fee9ff"
    "50ffc2ff3cffdbff66ffaeff61ffcaff"
    "7cffcfff62ffe7ff6effdcff7dffe7ff"
    "76fff4ff79ffecff2eff610039ff0000"
    "6cff59006eff4c0081ff4e009fff1500"
    "64ff2e00a5ff34005fff2e00b7ff0e00"
    "a5ff3e00c5ff1700baff2300d7ff1000"
    "d9ff1e00d5ff2400c2ff1a00dcff2600"
    "d3ff5700ceff5700ceff3900d6ff1600"
    "ceff6e00d0ff6700c5ff4600d4ff8500"
    "e3ff4300ebff6a00e5ff3100e1ff4f00"
    "e7ff3b00d6ff5000feff4d00f9ff5c00"
    "f4ff510006003d00130046000f003f00"
    "0d0044001b004b0001005b0004005800"
    "0300560000004e00"
)

good_bytes = (
    "535042584453d00200007b2254494d45"
    "42415345223a7b225343414c45223a22"
    "322e307573222c22484f464653455422"
    "3a35357d2c2253414d504c45223a7b22"
    "46554c4c53435245454e223a31353230"
    "2c22534c4f574d4f5645223a2d312c22"
    "444154414c454e223a313532302c2253"
    "414d504c4552415445223a2228313030"
    "4d532f7329222c2254595045223a2241"
    "564552616765222c224445504d454d22"
    "3a2234304d222c22505245434953494f"
    "4e223a327d2c224348414e4e454c223a"
    "5b7b224e414d45223a22434831222c22"
    "444953504c4159223a224f4646222c22"
    "43757272656e745f52617465223a3130"
    "3030302c2243757272656e745f526174"
    "696f223a31322e352c224d6561737572"
    "655f43757272656e745f537769746368"
    "223a224f4646222c22434f55504c494e"
    "47223a224143222c2250524f4245223a"
    "223158222c225343414c45223a22322e"
    "303056222c224f4646534554223a3231"
    "2c224652455155454e4345223a302c22"
    "494e5645525345223a224f4646227d2c"
    "7b224e414d45223a22434832222c2244"
    "4953504c4159223a224f4e222c224375"
    "7272656e745f52617465223a31303030"
    "302c2243757272656e745f526174696f"
    "223a312e32352c224d6561737572655f"
    "43757272656e745f537769746368223a"
    "224f4646222c22434f55504c494e4722"
    "3a224443222c2250524f4245223a2231"
    "58222c225343414c45223a223230306d"
    "56222c224f4646534554223a2d322c22"
    "4652455155454e4345223a302c22494e"
    "5645525345223a224f4646227d5d2c22"
    "4441544154595045223a225343524545"
    "4e222c2252554e535441545553223a22"
    "54524947222c2249444e223a224f574f"
    "4e2c58445333323032412c3137323030"
    "39312c56322e382e342e30222c224d4f"
    "44454c223a2233323032303131303222"
    "2c2254726967223a7b224d6f6465223a"
    "223f222c225377656570223a22415554"
    "4f227d2c224973536b69704966436c6f"
    "736564223a747275657de00b0000e20c"
    "020dd80c1b0de70c040dcb0c3d0dda0c"
    "440dc90cb70c4f0c830c490ccf0c770c"
    "c90c960ca90c740c870c660cbc0c790c"
    "d70cb30cd20cae0cec0cbb0c2f0dd40c"
    "540d060d730d2f0d6c0d260d480df60c"
    "140ded0c2e0d0c0d260dfc0c2c0def0c"
    "060da70cb60c870cc20c9a0cbc0c870c"
    "b00c750ca40c760cc60c910ce10cb40c"
    "d70ca40ce70cbf0cf00cc60c020dbc0c"
    "f80cb10ce20cb30c0c0dd00c180dd50c"
    "eb0cb10cfa0caa0c000dd60c120dcb0c"
    "fa0cc40cec0cbc0cdb0c9d0cda0c9e0c"
    "090dbc0cf80cc10cd00cab0cfd0cc90c"
    "fd0cb40c240daa0c690d1f0d810d150d"
    "370de30c210ddf0c3e0d180d2d0dc80c"
    "de0c900cbf0c9d0cc50c9e0c920c6f0c"
    "8f0c6e0c900c410c5e0c2a0c900c390c"
    "b40c8a0cbe0ca40cd20ca20ce10cc20c"
    "010dba0c170de20c2c0d160d200df90c"
    "170df20c160df20c080deb0c160de30c"
    "f60cab0ce60cbf0ce70cc70ce80ca60c"
    "aa0c890ceb0c8b0c3f0dca0c560de90c"
    "e00c920cf10cbc0c1a0dd90c330df20c"
    "020dba0cc60c710c8d0c5f0c890c490c"
    "a10c5d0c8f0c3d0c3b0c0c0c790c240c"
    "ec0c8f0cee0ca80cc30c8d0cd20c8e0c"
    "300dc00c530d1c0d5d0d2a0d450df50c"
    "150dd30c410d010d4e0dfa0c440de00c"
    "220dcc0c210d9b0c050d8d0cde0c810c"
    "d00c950cd40c9f0cc00c750cc50c7f0c"
    "b50c810ccc0c900ccf0c830cbb0c7b0c"
    "cb0c9a0c0e0dc00c010dd80cd40c860c"
    "b50c780cd20cad0ccc0c9c0cb40c8a0c"
    "c90c700ca60c770c8f0c6b0cb70c700c"
    "a30c7e0cb10c810cd30ca90cde0cb10c"
    "ee0cb90c180de70c150df50c060df00c"
    "2f0d030d4c0d2e0d3b0d100d160df20c"
    "190df00cf80cd10ce90cbd0cd30cb10c"
    "d20c8c0cb80c800cbb0c750c9c0c7f0c"
    "9b0c600ca40c7c0cb50c770ca90c700c"
    "cc0c930c0b0dd30c0b0de90cfa0cae0c"
    "f40cbf0c200ded0c100dd90ce30caa0c"
    "d30cb60ced0cb90cdd0ca20ccd0c980c"
    "b20c7f0c9d0c6f0ca70c7a0cce0c900c"
    "d60cac0cd60ca90cd50cb70ce70cc40c"
    "050dd90c150de80c170dea0c160dee0c"
    "180de40c140de40c050deb0cf90cc90c"
    "ee0cbe0cd90cb20cce0ca50cb90c8c0c"
    "c30c9b0cb60c950ccc0c860c9d0c720c"
    "bb0c8d0cd10cae0ce50cc10ce30cb40c"
    "c80caa0cf00cb90c0b0de70c160de00c"
    "fc0ce10cfb0cc60c140dda0c2b0df90c"
    "f80cc00c000db30cf70ccf0ce00ca50c"
    "040dbe0cf70cc50cc00c840ce50c970c"
    "e80ca50cc50c860c010db40c020db40c"
    "d60c9a0c0b0dbd0c150dce0c000dbb0c"
    "0e0db40c030dbc0c150dd40c220dd40c"
    "040dcf0cfd0cc80cd80ca70cc40c9c0c"
    "d90c9f0cd50c9c0cea0ca10cdc0cac0c"
    "b40c850cdf0c8d0c080ddc0cfe0cd70c"
    "f30cd20c0b0dda0c1d0df00c360dfc0c"
    "3a0d0e0d140def0c170de90c1f0dfd0c"
    "140deb0cfa0ccf0cde0cc20ce60cba0c"
    "ec0cd00cd20c9c0c810c330c250cc40b"
    "950bc20a7b0ab509910932093409bb08"
    "8d08e407ab071a07f60682066706e205"
    "cb054b052d0591047604f803cf035503"
    "3103b4029002e301b001f500c5003b00"
    "0d0089ff56ffbafe86fe0ffef0fd57fd"
    "1cfd66fc41fca9fb9dfb1ffbf8fa54fa"
    "21faadf98bf9fdf8cef846f81ef89af7"
    "83f707f7e1f635f6fff59ef57cf5e6f4"
    "baf416f4dbf355f341f3c3f2acf220f2"
    "ebf15af113f170f047f0c6efb9ef4cef"
    "24ef81ee44eeb4ed89ed1bed08ed99ec"
    "85ecffebcceb4aeb1feb86ea4aeae3e9"
    "1eea90e9b8e942e9ffe84ee807e882e7"
    "78e700e703e791e647e687e54de5fae4"
    "fce4d7e4e9e497e42ee5a5e458e659e5"
    "eae7b2e69be951e83eeb0cea3aec7beb"
    "20ed74eceded58ed9dee0eee51efbdee"
    "02f07def59f00df0e7f06ef05af1fef0"
    "e6f17bf133f2f6f17ff235f204f39cf2"
    "6ff31cf3b4f379f3f8f3c0f353f406f4"
    "bef465f41bf5d2f44af50ff58ff533f5"
    "cbf584f511f6d4f54ff60af684f63ef6"
    "a7f678f6e1f6abf606f7d8f64bf70ff7"
    "78f755f7a4f778f7d5f79df710f8d6f7"
    "43f814f85ef83ff88af864f8b6f88cf8"
    "edf8bdf818f9e1f83ef901f948f919f9"
    "5df929f981f956f9b1f97ff9ddf9acf9"
    "f1f9c9f9f6f9c3f92bfaf3f935fa09fa"
    "57fa39fa6efa54fa8afa6cfaa3fa86fa"
    "c1faa0fad0faa8faedfac8fa01fbd8fa"
    "23fbfafa38fb14fb4efb36fb5efb2ffb"
    "70fb55fb8bfb62fb9cfb7dfbabfb83fb"
    "ccfbaefbdafbb9fbe5fbcbfbfbfbc9fb"
    "0afcedfb22fcfdfb2efc05fc41fc1afc"
    "57fc32fc68fc52fc6bfc53fc7cfc67fc"
    "94fc69fc9ffc77fcabfc8afcb9fc99fc"
    "c6fca1fcc2fca9fcdbfcbdfcf1fcd0fc"
    "05fde6fcf9fcddfc0afde6fc17fdfdfc"
    "3bfd18fd3bfd2afd32fd1afd40fd25fd"
    "5afd3cfd67fd4efd6efd5cfd79fd59fd"
    "88fd6cfd8dfd80fd91fd81fda2fd8afd"
    "affd9afdb0fd9bfdc3fda7fdcbfdbafd"
    "d3fdc0fdd7fdc1fde1fdc9fdf1fdd0fd"
    "fefdebfdfefde6fd0bfef0fd10fefcfd"
    "19fe0bfe1dfe0cfe1ffe0cfe29fe15fe"
    "3cfe26fe41fe26fe3ffe32fe54fe35fe"
    "50fe39fe53fe3cfe61fe48fe63fe4efe"
    "71fe5ffe79fe63fe7bfe66fe76fe61fe"
    "8cfe71fe8cfe71fe9bfe79fe9afe79fe"
    "a9fe8dfeaffe93feb2fe9afeaefe99fe"
    "b5fea2febdfea7fec7feacfecafeb4fe"
    "ccfeb0fed6feb8fed5febffedffebdfe"
    "ebfecdfeeafed8fee6fecafef3fecffe"
    "fdfee8fefbfee2fef4fee6fef2fedbfe"
    "00fff3fe06fff1fe02ffebfe09fff9fe"
    "19fffefe1ffff3fe27ff08ff28ff0fff"
    "29ff10ff29ff0dff34ff1eff37ff1eff"
    "3bff25ff2dff22ff35ff20ff3dff2bff"
    "43ff32ff48ff32ff46ff32ff4aff34ff"
    "4fff38ff57ff3fff56ff3fff5aff3dff"
    "58ff46ff5bff4dff5eff4cff60ff4eff"
    "5eff51ff5fff4bff60ff4eff6cff55ff"
    "74ff66ff6cff5fff6cff5bff78ff62ff"
    "77ff6aff79ff67ff7aff6aff7cff69ff"
    "85ff74ff8aff7cff89ff71ff83ff73ff"
    "86ff74ff91ff79ff96ff82ff95ff81ff"
    "8aff77ff87ff78ff94ff7dff99ff88ff"
    "91ff7eff99ff7affa2ff8dff9bff8eff"
    "9dff89ffa5ff8dffa8ff95ffa8ff94ff"
    "a7ff99ffa8ff9cffabff9bffacff9aff"
    "adff9bffaaff99ffadff9effb1ffa3ff"
    "b2ffa0ffb2ff9fffb7ffaaffb8ffaaff"
    "baffa5ffb4ffa5ffbaffaaffbdffaaff"
    "baffa4ffb9ffa9ffc0ffafffbdffafff"
    "bdffa5ffc4ffa8ffc4ffb2ffc8ffadff"
    "c5ffa4ffc5ffa9ffccffb2ffc8ffb8ff"
    "c5ffb0ffbeffadffccffb9ffd1ffbeff"
    "ceffc4ffceffb9ffd0ffbdffd6ffc5ff"
    "d1ffc1ffd3ffc1ffd3ffc8ffd3ffc2ff"
    "d0ffc2ffd1ffc4ffd4ffc6ffd2ffc1ff"
    "e0ffb7ffe5ffbdffdbffc1ffddffc4ff"
    "e3ffc3ffd8ffc8ffdfffc2ffe4ffc7ff"
    "d9ffcaffd8ffc8ffe3ffccffe9ffcdff"
    "e8ffc9ffdeffc7ffe9ffd0ffe5ffd4ff"
    "e4ffd5ffe8ffd1ffe3ffd3ffe4ffd2ff"
    "e1ffcfffe6ffd5ffe2ffd1ffe3ffd3ff"
    "e6ffd6ffe3ffd3ffe5ffd1ffe5ffd7ff"
    "e9ffd8ffecffdaffe8ffd7ffe5ffd6ff"
    "e4ffd6ffe7ffd6ffecffdbffe9ffddff"
    "eaffd7ffe8ffdaffeeffe0ffeeffe2ff"
    "efffdefff2ffe2ffecffe1ffeeffe3ff"
    "ecffdcfff1ffe0fff3ffdcffecffdcff"
    "ebffd9ffecffe0fff0ffe1ffecffdaff"
    "e8ffd6ffedffdcffedffe1ffedffe2ff"
    "ebffddffebffdeffedffe2ffebffe1ff"
    "e6ffd9fff2ffdefff6ffe2fff4ffe0ff"
    "f1ffdbffefffdefff5ffdffff3ffe4ff"
    "f8ffe6ffeeffe4fff1ffe4fff4ffe5ff"
    "f3ffe4ffeeffe1ffefffe2ffefffe0ff"
    "f2ffe7fff1ffe1fff4ffe2fff3ffe5ff"
    "f7ffe3fff5ffdffff3ffe1fff2ffdeff"
    "f0ffe2fff4ffe3fff1ffdffff0ffe2ff"
    "f3ffe5fff4ffe4fff0ffe1fff8ffe5ff"
    "f4ffe5fff2ffe7fff0ffe4fff8ffe2ff"
    "f6ffe4fff3ffe7ffefffe6fff1ffe2ff"
    "f1ffe2fff5ffe3fff5ffe3fff3ffdfff"
    "eeffdffff3ffe5fff9ffe4fff6ffddff"
    "f6ffe0fff6ffe3fff2ffe4fff4ffe7ff"
    "f6ffe7fff8ffeafff5ffecfff8ffebff"
    "f6ffebfffbfff0fff8ffedfff9ffe9ff"
    "f8ffecfffaffebfff9ffeffff7ffecff"
    "f9ffe9fff8ffe9fff6ffecfff4ffe8ff"
    "f6ffebfffcfff0fffffff0fffdfff0ff"
    "fdffeffffffff1ff0000f0ff0700f6ff"
    "100000001700050019000c0029001700"
    "3400230040002c0050003a0060004900"
    "74005c00870067009b008200b1009800"
    "cd00b300ee00cc000d01ec0035010a01"
    "6001400181015701ad018b01ee01b601"
    "2502f90162022b029d027102e702a502"
    "3f03f80291034c03c803a0033004d703"
    "8c044204f204a204360500059d054d05"
    "e305ad055e06fa05a40669060107ba06"
    "5c071607ab0771070508a60744080008"
    "6a080f085b082708d50859083909ea08"
    "500923096f091d09a4095a09f409"
)



def HeaderToJSON(file):
    start = file.read(10)
    print(start)

    chID = bytes()
    count = 0
    while True:
        s = file.read(1)
        chID += s
        if s == b'}':
            count += 1
            if count == 6:
                break

    noise2 = file.read(4)

    return json.loads(chID)


def main():
    names = ["good", "bad"]
    for idx, data in enumerate([good_bytes, bad_bytes]):
        print(names[idx], "*"*40, "\n")
        data_file = BytesIO(bytes.fromhex(data))
        json_data = HeaderToJSON(data_file)
        print(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Full transcript from run:

```
good **************************************** 

b'SPBXDS\xd0\x02\x00\x00'
{
    "TIMEBASE": {
        "SCALE": "2.0us",
        "HOFFSET": 55
    },
    "SAMPLE": {
        "FULLSCREEN": 1520,
        "SLOWMOVE": -1,
        "DATALEN": 1520,
        "SAMPLERATE": "(100MS/s)",
        "TYPE": "AVERage",
        "DEPMEM": "40M",
        "PRECISION": 2
    },
    "CHANNEL": [
        {
            "NAME": "CH1",
            "DISPLAY": "OFF",
            "Current_Rate": 10000,
            "Current_Ratio": 12.5,
            "Measure_Current_Switch": "OFF",
            "COUPLING": "AC",
            "PROBE": "1X",
            "SCALE": "2.00V",
            "OFFSET": 21,
            "FREQUENCE": 0,
            "INVERSE": "OFF"
        },
        {
            "NAME": "CH2",
            "DISPLAY": "ON",
            "Current_Rate": 10000,
            "Current_Ratio": 1.25,
            "Measure_Current_Switch": "OFF",
            "COUPLING": "DC",
            "PROBE": "1X",
            "SCALE": "200mV",
            "OFFSET": -2,
            "FREQUENCE": 0,
            "INVERSE": "OFF"
        }
    ],
    "DATATYPE": "SCREEN",
    "RUNSTATUS": "TRIG",
    "IDN": "OWON,XDS3202A,1720091,V2.8.4.0",
    "MODEL": "320201102",
    "Trig": {
        "Mode": "?",
        "Sweep": "AUTO"
    },
    "IsSkipIfClosed": true
}
bad **************************************** 

b'SPBXDSJ\x03\x00\x00'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user1/stack_overflow/read_osc_file_orig.py", line 520, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/user1/stack_overflow/read_osc_file_orig.py", line 515, in main
    json_data = HeaderToJSON(data_file)
  File "/home/user1/stack_overflow/read_osc_file_orig.py", line 507, in HeaderToJSON
    return json.loads(chID)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 820 (char 819)
```

Comment: complete traceback is required. present a [mre], not just a single function.

Comment: Alright, added source code

Comment: off-site code is not okay. put it all in your question post. -- [mre] means *minimal* (and reproducible). see about simplifying your code. that is part of debugging. you are supposed to do that so others don't have to do your work for you. please review the article very carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken a look at the data and I think there is a more efficient way to do this that doesn't give an error.

The first 6 bytes appear to be some kind of preamble. The next four bytes appear to the the length of the JSON header information. This allows the JSON data to be extracted and passed to Python's json library.

Here is the code I did to test this:

```py
import json
from io import BytesIO

# Data omitted to make readable
# good_bytes = ( ... )
# bad_bytes = ( ... )

def header_to_json(file):
    raw_data = file.read()
    preamble = raw_data[:6]
    print(preamble)
    header_len = int.from_bytes(raw_data[6:10], 'little')
    json_start = 10
    json_stop = header_len + 10
    return json.loads(raw_data[json_start:json_stop])


def main():
    tests = {"good": good_bytes, "bad": bad_bytes}
    for test_name, test_data in tests.items():
        print(test_name, "*"*40, "\n")
        data_file = BytesIO(bytes.fromhex(test_data))
        json_data = header_to_json(data_file)
        print(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

which gave the following output:

```json
good **************************************** 

b'SPBXDS'
{
    "TIMEBASE": {
        "SCALE": "2.0us",
        "HOFFSET": 55
    },
    "SAMPLE": {
        "FULLSCREEN": 1520,
        "SLOWMOVE": -1,
        "DATALEN": 1520,
        "SAMPLERATE": "(100MS/s)",
        "TYPE": "AVERage",
        "DEPMEM": "40M",
        "PRECISION": 2
    },
    "CHANNEL": [
        {
            "NAME": "CH1",
            "DISPLAY": "OFF",
            "Current_Rate": 10000,
            "Current_Ratio": 12.5,
            "Measure_Current_Switch": "OFF",
            "COUPLING": "AC",
            "PROBE": "1X",
            "SCALE": "2.00V",
            "OFFSET": 21,
            "FREQUENCE": 0,
            "INVERSE": "OFF"
        },
        {
            "NAME": "CH2",
            "DISPLAY": "ON",
            "Current_Rate": 10000,
            "Current_Ratio": 1.25,
            "Measure_Current_Switch": "OFF",
            "COUPLING": "DC",
            "PROBE": "1X",
            "SCALE": "200mV",
            "OFFSET": -2,
            "FREQUENCE": 0,
            "INVERSE": "OFF"
        }
    ],
    "DATATYPE": "SCREEN",
    "RUNSTATUS": "TRIG",
    "IDN": "OWON,XDS3202A,1720091,V2.8.4.0",
    "MODEL": "320201102",
    "Trig": {
        "Mode": "?",
        "Sweep": "AUTO"
    },
    "IsSkipIfClosed": true
}
bad **************************************** 

b'SPBXDS'
{
    "TIMEBASE": {
        "SCALE": "5.0us",
        "HOFFSET": -402
    },
    "SAMPLE": {
        "FULLSCREEN": 1520,
        "SLOWMOVE": -1,
        "DATALEN": 1520,
        "SAMPLERATE": "(100MS/s)",
        "TYPE": "AVERage",
        "DEPMEM": "1M",
        "PRECISION": 2
    },
    "CHANNEL": [
        {
            "NAME": "CH1",
            "DISPLAY": "OFF",
            "Current_Rate": 10000,
            "Current_Ratio": 12.5,
            "Measure_Current_Switch": "OFF",
            "COUPLING": "AC",
            "PROBE": "10X",
            "SCALE": "200mV",
            "OFFSET": 50,
            "FREQUENCE": 0,
            "INVERSE": "OFF"
        },
        {
            "NAME": "CH2",
            "DISPLAY": "ON",
            "Current_Rate": 10000,
            "Current_Ratio": 0.625,
            "Measure_Current_Switch": "OFF",
            "COUPLING": "AC",
            "PROBE": "1X",
            "SCALE": "100mV",
            "OFFSET": 31,
            "FREQUENCE": 30030.031,
            "INVERSE": "OFF"
        }
    ],
    "DATATYPE": "SCREEN",
    "RUNSTATUS": "TRIG",
    "IDN": "OWON,XDS3202A,1720091,V2.8.4.0",
    "MODEL": "320201102",
    "Trig": {
        "Mode": "SINGle",
        "Type": "EDGE",
        "Items": {
            "Channel": "CH2",
            "Level": "-24.0mV",
            "Edge": "RISE",
            "Coupling": "DC",
            "HoldOff": "100ns"
        },
        "Sweep": "AUTO"
    },
    "IsSkipIfClosed": true
}
```